# Is it possible to uninstall the Google Play Store without affecting Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I have a rooted Samsung Galaxy a50 with a stock ROM installed. However, after using an app (System App Remover) to uninstall Google Play Store (I removed the Google App also) — many apps simply crash on load, and I am familiar with the

> App won't run without Google Play services, which are not supported by your device

error. Perhaps I've forgotten something else that might come into play (I rooted this device a while ago) but reading around it seems these apps are somewhat tethered together and the way to separate them is not entirely clear.

I am confused because I still have `GmsCore.apk`, `GoogleServicesFramework.apk` (not `Phonesky.apk`) in `/system/priv-app`, so I'm unsure as to exactly what the problem might be.

I'm aware that to do this right will almost certainly require a re-flashing my phone, but at this stage I still feel I'm just firing into the dark so if anyone has some light to shed on the right path it would be very much appreciated.

**TL;DR:**

I want to remove the Google Play Store without affecting apps that rely on Google Play Services. Is this possible/reasonable to achieve with a stock ROM on a rooted phone?

Comment: **NO**. Why? Tap on the Play Store tag you used and see it's tag wiki (click on *learn more*), repeat on other tag.

Answer (score 2):

Some apps are dependent on google play store links...

They have to be installed separately (or the link must be broken)

My method: install from alt APK source (like aptoide)
you can patch the apps with a good app manager to 
"break play store link" (thats the command option in said app manager)

However... Some apps yet require license validation.
This requires a patch. "Lucky patcher" is good at this...

And since im sure some disclaimer is needed... Lucky patcher can be used to pirate apps, but serves many functions, and if you own a license to said app... you are not "breaking any rules"

Comment: Play Store links like `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp` work on a device without Google Play Store installed they just open in web browser as they are valid web links. Of course download is not possible on the GooglePlay web site.

Comment: link meaning the app "Checks" with google play when it starts up... 

However... that is irrelevant when installing them seperate. an app manager "Breaks that link" meaning, stops it from caring about google play store...

Comment: Two additions to the license check: 1. Even free apps can perform a "license check" if they want to download an "APK Extension file" via GooglePlay. 2. Google recommends to perform license checks not in-app on client side but on server side. Lucky Patcher will not work in that situation. See https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing